# convert cps to Promise in node.js Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following method in node.js using `cps`:

```
exports.execute = function (input, callback) {
    var config = {...};
    var conn = mysql.createConnection(config);

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (null !== err) {
            var message = {
                "level": "error",
                "message": err
            };
            console.log(message);
            callback(JSON.stringify(message));
        }
    });


   /* cps for async */
    cps.seq([
        /**
         * @function
         * @name validate
         * @param _
         * @param handle
         */
        function (ignore, handle) {
            if (null !== input.test) {
                conn.query(input.test.query, handle);
            } else {
                handle(null, null);
            }
        },
        /**
         * @function
         * @name query
         * @param res
         * @param handle
         */
        function (res, handle) {
            if ((null === res && null === input.test) || true === input.test.validate(res)) {
                if (input.query !== null) {
                    conn.query(input.query, handle);
                } else {
                    handle(null, null);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                var message = {
                    "level": "error",
                    "message": input.test.error
                };
                console.log(message);
                callback(JSON.stringify(message));
                conn.end();
                return;
            }
        },
        function (res, handle) {
            console.log("[RDS-BASE] Executing input action");
            handle(null, input.action(res));
        },
        function (res, ignore) {
            console.log("[RDS-BASE] Executing response");
            if (null === res) {
                var message = {
                    "level": "error",
                    "message": "Missing result"
                };
                console.log(message);
                callback(JSON.stringify(message));
                conn.end();
                return;
            }
            callback(null, res);
            conn.end();
            return;
        }
    ], handle);
};
```

How can I refactor my code using `Promise` or any other ways to replace `cps` functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to promisify the cps style functions that you call, which are `conn.connect` and `conn.query`

You can use `util.promisify` for this

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
. . .
conn.connect = promisify(conn.connect);
conn.query = promisify(conn.query);
```

Then you can use async/await to streamline your code

```
exports.execute = async function (input) {
    . . .
    await conn.connect();
    let res = await conn.query(input.test.query);
    . . .
}
```

Then when you want to use execute, you can use `.then`/`.catch` or wrap it in `async`/`await`